# Laravel Backpack. 1-1 (one-to-one) relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-backpack

I have 2 Eloquent models:

```
/**
* Entities/Products.php
*/
use CrudTrait;

protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'macronutrients_id',
];

public function macronutrients()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Macronutrients::class);
}


/**
* Entities/Macronutrients.php
*/
use CrudTrait;

protected $fillable = [
    'proteins', 'fats', 'carbons', 'calories', 'product_id'
];

public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}
```

I don't know how I can show table (or something like list of options) with all macronutrients on product's edit page via Laravel Backpack CRUD?

In other words, I want to make something like this:

on page http://example.com/admin/product/2/edit:

```
* [text] Name

* Macronutrients:
[number] proteins
[number] fats
[number] carbons
[number] calories
```

where [text], [number] is input fields.

Comment: you can use One To Many relation instead One To One

Comment: In One To Many I can't create new values, only select from exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this with some custom logic. As a result:

[Screenshot of my /admin/product/1/edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABTXX.png)

First of all, I created custom field:

```
<!-- /resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud/fields/product_macronutrients.blade.php -->

<!-- product_macronutrients -->

@php($macronutrients = isset($entry) ? $entry->macronutrients : false)

<div @include('crud::inc.field_wrapper_attributes') >

    @include('crud::inc.field_translatable_icon')

    <div class="array-container form-group">

        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped m-b-0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-center">{{-- <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>--}} </th>
                    @foreach( $field['columns'] as $column )
                        <th style="font-weight: 300!important;">
                            // l10n strings (productscatalog::labels.proteins, productscatalog::labels.fats and so on)
                            @lang("productscatalog::labels.$column")
                        </th>
                    @endforeach
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody ui-sortable="sortableOptions" class="table-striped">
                <tr class="array-row">
                    <td>
                            <p><b>@lang("productscatalog::labels.macrontr")</b></p>
                    </td>
                    @foreach( $field['columns'] as $column)
                        <td>
                            <input
                                class="form-control input-sm"
                                type="text"
                                name="{{ $column }}"
                                value="{{ old($column) ? old($column) : $macronutrients ? $macronutrients->$column : '' }}"
                                @include('crud::inc.field_attributes')
                            />
                        </td>
                    @endforeach
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
</div>
```

And `ProductCrudController`:

```
public function setup()
{
    // other stuff...

    $this->crud->addField([
        'label'         => 'Macronutrients',
        'type'          => 'product_macronutrients',
        'name'          => '',
        'columns'       => [
            'proteins',
            'fats',
            'carbons',
            'calories',
        ],
    ]);
}


public function store(StoreRequest $request)
{
    $redirect_location = parent::storeCrud($request);

    $this->storeOrUpdateMacronutrients($request, $this->crud->entry);

    return $redirect_location;
}

public function update(UpdateRequest $request)
{
    $redirect_location = parent::updateCrud($request);

    $this->storeOrUpdateMacronutrients($request, $this->crud->entry);

    return $redirect_location;
}

public function destroy($id)
{
    $this->destroyMacronutrients($id);

    $return = parent::destroy($id);

    return $return;
}

protected function storeOrUpdateMacronutrients(Request $request, Product $product)
{
    $macronutrients = Macronutrients::firstOrNew(['id' => $product->id]);

    $macronutrients->proteins   = $request->input('proteins');
    $macronutrients->fats       = $request->input('fats');
    $macronutrients->carbons    = $request->input('carbons');
    $macronutrients->calories   = $request->input('calories');

    $macronutrients->save();
}

protected function destroyMacronutrients($productId)
{
    $macronutrients = Macronutrients::findOrFail($productId);

    $macronutrients->delete();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->crud->addColumn([
    // 1-n relationship
    'label' => "Country name", // Table column heading
    'type' => "select",
    'name' => 'country_name', // the column that contains the ID of that connected entity;
    'entity' => 'country', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
    'attribute' => "country_name", // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
    'model' => "App\Models\Country",
]);
```

this is an example for 1-n relationship in laravel backpack